# How to loop through all td elements in table adding a different colour from sass colour map?

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to loop through all the `<td>` elements of my table matching each element to a colour I have set up in a sass map called $options-colours. At the moment Im tripping up however as only the first 3 colours keep repeating because of the new `<tr>` each time. I understand that I need to increment the `<tr>` `nth-of-type` or `nth-child` every time my index is divisible by 3 but I'm not exactly sure how to piece it all together, can someone explain how I can make this work?

**SCSS**

```
 table {
  width: 100%;


    tr {
    @for $i from 1 through length($option-colours) {

      /*
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        if $i % 3 == 0 increment?
      }
      */

      td {
            width: 33.3333%;
            height: 100px;
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
            background: nth($option-colours, $i);
        }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/styler/pen/oCKfJ?editors=110

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So if you have 3 rows with 3 columns, you're expecting the 1st cell of the 1st row to be a different color than the 1st cell of the 2nd row?

Comment: yeah basically i have a colour map so i want to loop through the tr td 1, 2, 3 and give those tds the first 3 colours in the map, then increment to tr:nth-child(1) td 1,2,3 but this time colours 4,5,6 in map etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I created a few variables to track which row we should be styling as well as which cell. After three iterations of the loop, the cell counter is reset to 1 and the row counter is incremented. I'm not really sure what best practices are for organizing big SASS loops like this, so any feedback is welcome.

http://codepen.io/sdsanders/pen/nchtb?editors=110

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  $row: 1;
  $cell: 1;

    tr {
    @for $i from 1 through length($option-colours) {

      &:nth-child(#{$row}) {
        td {
          &:nth-child(#{$cell}) {
            background: nth($option-colours, $i);
          }
          $cell: $cell + 1;
          @if $cell == 4 {
            $cell: 1;
            $row: $row +1;
          }
        } 
      }
    }

    td {
      width: 33.3333%;
      height: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

Relevant CSS output looks like this:

```
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fcfcfc;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ebebea;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7d7d6;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) {
  background: #c2c2c1;
}
...
```

Comment: this is awesome!! i constantly confuse myself when trying to approach something like this, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The nth-child and nth-of-type selectors only count sibling elements.  In order for your CSS to work, your markup needs to have *all* of the td elements be siblings (eg. in the same row).

To keep your current markup, you have to tell Sass exactly how many columns or rows you are expecting to have.  This code allows you to specify the number of cells per row:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/vCLsm

```
$option-colours: (
  hsla(60,1,99,1),
  hsla(60,1,92,1),
  hsla(60,1,84,1),
  hsla(60,1,76,1),
  hsla(60,1,68,1),
  hsla(60,1,60,1),
  hsla(60,1,52,1),
  hsla(60,1,44,1),
  hsla(60,1,36,1),
  hsla(60,1,28,1),
  hsla(60,1,20,1),
  hsla(60,1,12,1)
); 

$cells: 3;
table {
  width: 100%;

  td {
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 100px;
  }

  @for $i from 1 through length($option-colours) {
    $row: ceil($i / $cells);
    tr:nth-child(#{$row}) {
      $cell:  $cells - ($row * $cells - $i);
      td:nth-child(#{$row}n+#{$cell}) { // `#{$row}n+` is optional
        background: nth($option-colours, $i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1n+1) {
  background: #fcfcfc;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1n+2) {
  background: #ebebea;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1n+3) {
  background: #d7d7d6;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #c2c2c1;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: #aeaead;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background: #9a9a98;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: #868683;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background: #71716f;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: #5d5d5b;
}
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: #484847;
}
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: #343432;
}
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: #1f1f1e;
}
```